# Difficulty calling functions with Q.js "then" without parenthesis

Tags: jquery, promise, q

I have assembled a small tool for use on my page, and for the most part it seems to function, but I'm having a bit of a strange behavior when I try to plug it into `Q.js`.

Normally, as I understand it, you can call functions in this manner.

```
Q(manager.tasks.init)
   .then(manager.tasks.start)
   .then(manager.tasks.fulfill)
   .then(manager.tasks.finish);
```

However I am not seeming to be able to do this, instead I have to call them and explicitly invoke them like functions, like this.

```
Q(manager.tasks.init())
   .then(manager.tasks.start())
   .then(manager.tasks.fulfill())
   .then(manager.tasks.finish());
```

The complete code is visible here;

### [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/wuwig/1/edit)

Now, I am fine with using the parenthesis, but I do not understand **why** it is doing this. I want to understand what is going on here, so any information is appreciated.

Comment: Just guessing here, but perhaps you need to use `.then(manager.tasks.start.bind(manager.tasks))` to get the `this` ptr set appropriately when your method is called.  Your second version will not work properly when you actually have async operations in your methods.

Comment: Alright, I made an adjustment to it.

Comment: So you made what adjustment and what happened?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought I said more. I'm a bit absentminded I suppose. I forgot to change the `tasks` to an object literal, instead of a function. The second way of calling the functions is working for me with async functions.

Comment: So, if you make the change I suggested, then what happens?  I don't know if you've tried my suggestion and it all works fine now or you tried my suggestion and learned something else.  You're using `this` in your methods so it must be set appropriately.

Comment: Your 2nd method calls `.init()`, `.start()`, `.fulfill()` and `.finish()` in order, but does not wait for any async things in any of them to finish before calling the next ones.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it made no difference that I could discern.

Comment: It waits for them, yeah. That's what `Q` is doing. That's why they are wrapped in `then`, and they return a `promise`.

Comment: Nope.  It's pure javascript (nothing Q can do to change it) that executes those four methods one after the other without waiting for any async operations inside of them in your 2nd block of code.  If you think it's waiting for async operations, you either don't have any async operations or you're just being fooled.

Comment: That's kind of the point of what I am asking for help with. They are not running right, but I've copied things from every tutorial exactly. I've done async just fine with inline functions. I am trying to figure out __why__ they aren't working.

Comment: I've done this before with another layout, I was just trying to clean it up and make it a bit less disorganized: http://jsbin.com/kukifu/1/edit - it works fine here. I'm not understanding what is so different between the two, though.

Comment: I mean, if you look between the two, the formula is pretty basic. I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't. They both return a promise, they're both functions, the overall inside of the functions isn't changed.

Comment: Alright... I have a moment to actually sit down now. Sorry, was extremely busy with people coming in and out. I'll try to be more clear. I did this before (http://jsbin.com/kukifu/1/edit) and it worked fine. I was merely trying to move it to a cleaner structure and make it a bit nicer and more polished. I cannot figure out what the difference is though, as far as interaction with `Q` is concerned. Both are made up of functions that return a `promise` for `Q`.

Comment: You don't pass a promise to `.then()` which is what your second implementation is doing because your functions will be executed `immediately` and their return value will be passed to `.then()`.  You pass a function reference to `.then()` and then when bluebird executes that function sometime later, that function can return a promise (or other data depending upon the situation).  This example http://jsbin.com/kukifu/1/edit is doing the right thing.  It's passing a function reference to `.then()` which can be called later.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't understand. They look the exact same. They're both functions in each situation. I have no idea what `bluebird` is.

Comment: You see the `()` at the end of the functions inside the `.then(manager.tasks.start())` in your second implementation.  That means those functions are getting executed immediately and their return value is being passed to `.then()`.  That's a huge difference with what you're doing in http://jsbin.com/kukifu/1/edit where the function reference is being passed to `.then()` so Q can call it LATER.

Comment: Right. I don't want that. I want to run it like the first version. But I don't understand why it won't run that way. I cannot see any difference in the functions between both jsBins. The only difference is the external wrapper.

Comment: Difference between which two jsBins?

Comment: This one: http://jsbin.com/wuwig/5/edit -- and this one: http://jsbin.com/kukifu/1/edit -- all of the functions are declared exactly the same way, so I do not see how the behavior can possibly be different.

Comment: They are not declared the same because of your use of a nested object definition and your use of `this` in the methods.  Plus, this one http://jsbin.com/wuwig/1/edit has no async code in it either which can mask issues.  In this one http://jsbin.com/wuwig/1/edit, what do you expect `this` to be when those methods are called?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm just copying what I've learned. I have absolutely no clue why it is required, I've been going through every single tutorial and website I can possibly find on javascript/jquery to get this far.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're even seeing a `return this;` in the latest one I linked.

Comment: I'm talking about all the lines of code like this `$(this).trigger("init:begin");`.  What is `this` supposed to point to in that?

Comment: It's supposed to be the `manager.tasks` object.

Comment: OK, that's one reason why this one http://jsbin.com/wuwig/1/edit doesn't work because `this` will not be set to that when Q calls those methods.  It will either be set to the global object (in regular mode) or set to `undefined` (in strict mode).  Either probably causing an error and causes execution to stop.  That's why I said you had to use `.bind()` in my very first comment to make sure `this` was set correctly.  We need to go back to that and go from there as there may be other things wrong too.  Are you looking in the debug console to see what JS errors you have?

Comment: Alright, thank you. I need to step away from my keyboard for a moment, I'm feeling rather sick. I will try to rework some of this and post an update soon. I am sorry for all of the trouble.

Comment: Also, please make sure you're looking in the debug console and relaying ANY errors you see there.  The above mistake should have caused an error/exception somewhere unless Q silently swallowed it.

Comment: I try to, but debugging on jsbin is always frustrating. It never really points to the code, it points to jsbin's tools.

Comment: I don't use jsbin myself, but on jsFiddle (something similar), you just have to make sure you're inspecting the right frame with the debug tools (where your code is actually executing).

Comment: Alright, I quickly made some edits according to what I understand of what you said. Can you see if this looks more correct? It _appears_ to do what I want, but I'm still new to async stuff, so I'm not 100% certain if it does. http://jsbin.com/wuwig/5/edit

Comment: Progress.  Though I don't see any structural issues any more, you still don't have any async operations in that one (all the promises are resolved upon first calling the function) so that isn't yet a good test of whether it's really working yet for async functions.  If you can resolve some of the promises only on a `setTimeout()` and make the first ones a longer time than the later ones, that would be a better test to see if the sequencing it still correct.

Comment: Alright, I did what you suggested and it seems to work, you can see it here: http://jsbin.com/wuwig/5/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documenting some of what we went through in the comments above and in the comments on my answer...

Neither of your above solutions is actually coded correctly.  The first one has issues because `this` won't be set property when your callbacks are called by Q.

When you do it like this:

```
Q(manager.tasks.init)
   .then(manager.tasks.start)
   .then(manager.tasks.fulfill)
   .then(manager.tasks.finish);
```

Q will call those methods, but the `this` pointer will not be set to `manager.tasks` like you want.  So, when you do things like this in the methods:

```
$(this).trigger("init:begin");
```

Then `this` won't be what you want and it will throw an exception and stop executing.  You can solve that by either doing this:

```
Q(manager.tasks.init.bind(manager.tasks))
   .then(manager.tasks.start.bind(manager.tasks))
   .then(manager.tasks.fulfill.bind(manager.tasks))
   .then(manager.tasks.finish.bind(manager.tasks));
```

which will cause `this` to be set to `manager.tasks`.  Or, you can remove any usage of `this` in those methods so they become static methods (which is what it appears you chose to do).

---

The second one was not passing a function reference to `.then()` like it is supposed to.

When you do it like this:

```
Q(manager.tasks.init())
   .then(manager.tasks.start())
   .then(manager.tasks.fulfill())
   .then(manager.tasks.finish());
```

The JS interpreter is calling your functions immediately (that's what happens when you put the `()` on the end) and passing the return value from those functions to each of the `.then()` lines.  That is not what you want.  `.then()` wants a function reference passed to it so that the promise library can execute the function sometime later.  In your case your functions were returning a promise which is not what you should be passing to `.then()`.

Because you have no actual async operations in these methods, this appeared to work as it called the operations in sequence, but as soon as you had an async operation in any of them that was actually resolving the promise, it would not work correctly.

---

For the issue with your fulfill method, it needs to be like this where you use the deferred/promise you created named `results` in your reduce operation.  I also changed it to run the reduce before the `setTimeout()` since it just seems a little cleaner to me (easier to understand).  You're setting up all the work to be done and then in the `setTimeout()` you're kicking off the work by resolving the first deferred in the chain.

Then, it returns the chained promise that comes back from the `list.reduce()` operation and uses a chained `.then()` handler on that to know when to output the `"fulfill:end"` message.

```
manager.tasks.fulfill = function () {
    // alert the task manager that we're beginning this phase
    $(manager.tasks).trigger("fulfill:begin");

    // create a placeholder for the result of all of the items in the list
    var results = Q.defer();

    setTimeout(function(){
        // resolve the first defer we created to 
        //    let the `.then()` chain start to run
        results.resolve();
    }, 6000);

    // now add all then `.then()` onto the results
    // these functions won't run yet because the first defer has not yet resolved
    return list.reduce(function(i, f) {
        return i.then(f);
    }, results.promise).then(function() {
        // alert the task manager that we're ending this phase
        // after all the callback promises have finished
        $(manager.tasks).trigger("fulfill:end");
    });
};
```

---

I think the `.enqueue()` issue will be fixed if your callback returns the promise like this:

```
  manager.tasks.enqueue(function(deferred){
    return function(){
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log('test');
        deferred.resolve();     
      }, 3000);
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  });
```

If this were me, I'd probably change the `.enqueue()` implementation so that it handles the returning of the promise (since it was the one that created it), but a quick solution here is to just make sure your callback returns the promise when it is executed.

You can see a derivation of your jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JxJVs/ with these changes implemented that generates the exact output you showed you wanted in your JPEG.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much. I will have the time in a few moments to sit down and read over this. I am mobile at the moment.

Comment: I see! That's absolutely brilliant! It's so simple and obvious, but I kept missing it. It's completely clear once you see it once. That's completely ingenious! You are amazing!

Comment: I will make a new question here in a bit for you, so that you can get the points correctly - since you _did_ literally answer two questions instead of one. It is also a good thing to have visible for others, because I surely cannot be the only person with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ciel,

Not wishing to detract from jFriend's significant help, and I know this whole thing is only a straw model for something larger, but now you have a working solution you might like to consider tidying it up to make something slightly more manageable.

In a nutshell, this is what I have done :

- Defined the singleton `manager` as a module (vis-à-vis the Module Pattern). The ugly `manager.tasks` is no longer required and disappears.
- Avoided the need to build list as an array then `.reduce(...)` it, by building the desired `.then()` chain directly.
- Avoided the need to double-wrap functions passed to `enqueue()`. This also avoided the assumption that such functions will need a Deferred passed to them. Those functions that do need a Deferred, can generate their own.
- Avoided the need to trigger events on a synthetic jQuery object for the purpose of messaging.
- For compactness, used jQuery throughout, exploiting the "detachability" of its Deferreds' `resolve` and `reject` methods. Reversion to Q should be reasonably trivial, though the code will tend to expand again.
- For compactness, used `return $.Deferred(function(){...})...;` in several places.
- For compactness, used `fn.bind()` in several places.

Enough preamble, here's the code :

```
//Module pattern
var manager = (function($) {
    //Private vars
    var queueStarter, queue;

    //Private functions
    function message(m) { console.log(m); }

    //Private functions to be made public
    function clearQueue() {
        queueStarter = queue = $.Deferred();
    }
    function enqueue(f) {
        queue = queue.then(f);
    }
    function init() {
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            message("init:begin");
            setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, 2000);
        }).then(message.bind(null, "init:end"));
    }
    function start() {
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            message("start:begin");
            setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, 2000);
        }).then(message.bind(null, "start:end"));
    }
    function fulfill() {
        message("fulfill:begin");
        setTimeout(queueStarter.resolve, 2000);
        return queue.then(message.bind(null, "fulfill:end"));
    }
    function finish() {
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            message("finish:begin");
            setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, 2000);
        }).then(message.bind(null, "finish:end"));
    }

    clearQueue();

    //Expose private functions as public
    return {
        clearQueue: clearQueue,
        enqueue: enqueue,
        init: init,
        start: start,
        fulfill: fulfill,
        finish: finish
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function($) {
    manager.enqueue(function() {
        return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            console.log('test');
            setTimeout(dfrd.resolve, 1000);
        }).promise();
    });

    $.when().then(manager.init)
       .then(manager.start)
       .then(manager.fulfill)
       .then(manager.finish);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uF95f/2/)**

Hopefully you'll find some useful stuff in there - nothing sacred - use/ignore as you see fit.

### EDIT

An attempt to answer questions asked in comments below ...

**Building the list/queue**

In the code above, `queue` is built as follows :

```
queueStarter = queue = $.Deferred();//initially
queue = queue.then(fn1);//first call of enqueue()
queue = queue.then(fn2);//second call of enqueue()
queue = queue.then(fn3);//third call of enqueue()
//etc
```

At this point, you have a `.then` chain equivalent to :

```
queue = $.Deferred().then(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3); //etc
```

But you also have `queueStarter`, which is a reference to the Deferred object at the left end of the chain, providing the means to set the chain in progress with `queueStarter.resove`, which appears in the `fulfill` method.

This has exactly the same effect as your original code, in which functions are pushed onto an array, to which `.reduce(...)` is eventually applied to (effectively) transform the array into a `.then` chain with a resolved starter promise at the left hand end.

You pay your money and take your pick on which you find more elegant - the overall effect is identical.

**The Module Pattern**

In the Module Pattern, each module is a singleton defined as a self-executing function that returns a javascript plain object which defines the module's public members. Each module can also have (and typically does have) private members, which are simply vars defined within the scope of the function. By defining public methods (functions) in the form of private vars then exposing them in the returned object, the methods can call each other without reference to the module's external member name (eg `manager`).

Google "javascript module pattern" for plenty of discussion on the subject.

**jQuery Deferreds/promises**

The critics of jQuery Deferreds tend to be *very* knowledgeable and I confess I don't understand every word on the subject. The criticisms revolve chiefly around (a) jQuery promises compliance with the Promises/A spec, not the later Promises/A+, which is concerned chiefly with interoperability of promises from different libs, by the detailed behaviour of .then(), and (b) error handling. In my experience, most of the time, javascript Deferreds/promises will do the job perfectly well, especially in a DOM environment where interoperability is far less of an issue than in server-side javascript (Node.js). Examples of where javascript Deferreds/promises can fall down are generally contrived, IMHO. You will find the phrase "throw-safe" used in connection with other promise libs, but that might as well be "throw-dangerous" IMHO - I tend to believe that Promise/A+'s throw behaviour is neither safe nor dangerous, if you know what you are doing - it's just a particular behaviour, which can be learned. As I'm sure you will appreciate, some of what I say here is contentious - as is almost everything on this topic until it stabilises in maybe a couple of years time.

That said, I only used jQuery Deferreds because I understand jQuery much better than Q, which is a limitation on my part. I really need to find time to sit down and learn new stuff, ... work ... family ... several other hobbies.

**[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**

This useful method was introduced at ES5.1, so fairly recently in the life of javascript. It is a convenient way to specify context (`this` within a function), and to pre-specify (some) arguments passed to a function. Probably the first thing to understand about `.bind()` is that it *returns a function*, which like the original function, is latent until executed - it's like an opera singer who has drawn breath and stands waiting for his cue to sing. In this regard, `.bind()` differs from the related Function methods `.call()` and `.apply()`, both of which cause immediate execution of a function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh wow, this is really incredible. I will try this out as soon as I can. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried this in my application and it does work, but I am confused about a few things. The most prominent is the way you replaced the `array`. It looks - to me - like it runs it as soon as it is added. Can you elaborate on what is _really_ going on here? I'm still not familiar enough with javascript, so the way you are doing that is kind of confusing to me.

Comment: My next question, if you are willing to answer it, is what actually makes this a 'module' pattern? I'm only familiar with modules from `Typescript`, so far. I'm still not sure what makes something qualify as a 'module'.

Comment: And my last question, I went with `Q.js` because I was under the understanding that jQuery promises were not very good. You can find more here: http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/ - do you think this is something I need to be cautious of, with this approach?

Comment: I'm also having a hard time figuring out what `message.bind(null, [text]));` is for.

Comment: Your code is gorgeous and elegant, though it sure leaves me realizing how dumb I am about javascript so far. I've learned a lot between the two answers provided. I'm not sure which I will use in my final project, but I've certainly come out with more knowledge.